# How to handle response promise with async function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to get some data through an API call to a database
but I have problem returning the data to the main function

```js
async function getKnackRecords(objID, filter, sortObj, recordID) {
  let api_url = `https://api.knack.com/v1/objects/object_${objID}/records`
  let options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers
  }

  if (typeof filter !== 'undefined') {
    api_url += '?filters=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(filter)) + '&sort_field=' + sortObj.field + '&sort_order=' + sortObj.order
  } else {
    api_url += '/' + recordID
  }

  let response = fetch(api_url, options)
  console.log(response) // executed 1st

  let records = response.then(await function(response) {

    console.log(response)  // executed 3rd
    data = response.json()

    return data.then(await async function(data) {

      console.log(data.records) // executed 5th
      return data.records
    })
    
  })
  console.log(records, 'outer')  // executed 2nd
  return response
```

In the main function call the getKnackRecord function

```js
let p = await getKnackRecords(objID, filter, sortObj)
console.log(p, 'main')  // executed 4th
```

I can't fix the execution order. I want to return the records from the API call but had been unsuccessful. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `await function(response) {…}` and `await async function(data) {…}` doesn't make sense. You shouldn't be using `.then()` at all when you want to use `async`/`await`!

Comment: Don't `return response`, but `return records` if that's the result you actually want!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need, and should not use async/await inside a promise.
Async/await use promises under the hood.
I'd suggest you to get comfortable with Promises before you try to use async/await.

Here is the MDN documentation for promises
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Your function with vanilla Promises:

```
function getSnackRecords(...myArgs){
    const url = ...
    const options = {...}

    return fetch(api_url, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => data.records)
}

...

getSnackRecords(...).then(records => doSomething(records))
```

With async/await:

```
async function getSnackRecords(...myArgs){
    const url = ...
    const options = {...}

    const response = await fetch(api_url, options)
    const data = await response.json()
    const records = data.records

    return records
}

...
async function someFn(){
    const records = await getSnackRecords(...)
    //do something
}
```

In very short, inside an **async** function you can **await** for an asynchronous task to be performed instead of wrapping it in **.then**

Comment: Thank you! Your response is very helpful! I quite new to async programming. My code didn't really make sense haha

Answer (score -1):

You could `return` a Promise from your `getKnackRecords()` function.
Than, outside of it, after requesting it you're good to go with another `.then()` chain:

```js
const getKnackRecords = (objID, filter, sortObj, recordID) => {
  const filt = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(filter));
  const api_url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${objID}` + (
    recordID ?
    `/${recordID}` : 
    `?filters=${filt}&sort_field=${sortObj.field}&sort_order=${sortObj.order}`
  );

  
  return fetch(api_url).then(res => res.json());   // <Promise>
};

getKnackRecords("todos", null, null, "24").then(resJSON => {
  console.log(resJSON);
});
```

Using `async / await`:

```js
const getKnackRecords = async (objID, filter, sortObj, recordID) => {
  const filt = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(filter));
  const api_url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${objID}` + (
    recordID ?
    `/${recordID}` : 
    `?filters=${filt}&sort_field=${sortObj.field}&sort_order=${sortObj.order}`
  );

  const res = await fetch(api_url);
  return await res.json();
};

(async() => {
  try {
    const data = await getKnackRecords("todos", null, null, "24");
    console.log(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: If you're using `.then()`, there's no need to make the function `async` though

Comment: @Bergi exactly! Thank you.